# Axios library Adds additional "/" between my post request endpoint parameters

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, vue.js, axios, google-chrome-devtools

I've a piece of code that sends a post request to my backend. Everything works fine for me.

However I have a vendor that are overseas facing a weird error. When they render my Vue Web Application, the POST request made to my backend has an additional "/" in between the parameters.
And i really do not know why it keeps happening at their end but not on me. We are both using the same browser.

Below is the library and part of the code that makes a request to my backend.

```
import axios from "axios";

export const HTTP = axios.create({
  baseURL: _baseURL,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    'Accept': "application/json"
  },
  timeout: 30000
});


HTTP.post(
  `/someotherparams/restapiparams/${this.someinput}/someparameter/${this.moreinput}`,
  {
      something: "some text"
})
```

At the Vendor's End when i check the network of the browser, it shows that it is firing the following :

"BaseUrl/someotherparams/restapiparams/${this.someinput}//someparameter/${this.moreinput}"

As you can see there's an additional "/". Advance thanks for some guidance.

Note*: I've check the codes many times, the data in the data base for the this.someinput (does not contain '/') values. It works well for me, it did occur once from my support team. but the vendor is facing this issue every time.

Comment: Did you check if the vendor uses some kind of browser extension(s) and what happens when you disable them?

Comment: I have not check about their browser extension affecting the request. but i do noticed that thye had some extensions running maybe i will try that. THANK YOU !

Comment: i tried to install the same extensions on my laptop. but it doesnt reproduce the error on my side @JKL

Comment: If you could get access to your vendors browser you could try debugging the script to see what the value of `${this.someinput}` is. If it contains an extra '/' try following the callstack backwards to find out when the extra '/' is added.

Comment: Hey @JKL , thank you for your help. i've went through with the vendor. apparently when loading the page from my responsed url, they did not use JSON.parse() in their javascript code. and thus additional / have been added!

Comment: Although it does not justify how did my support team got the error once.

Comment: Glad you found the solution. I don't understand how your vendor doesn't use `JSON.parse()` since I would expect you would run the exact same code as the vendor.